# How to force uniform rings in D3 ridal plot

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have successfully drawn a radial graph but the gap between the rings gets smaller and smaller the further out they go. I would like them to be uniform in distance apart.

I have tried altering the yticks / x ticks and also various scales I see that use PI... Doing the former, I've managed to get a uniform scale on my graphs... i.e steps of 2, rather than the code deciding for itself, but the rings still get closer together.

Without wanting to annoy by posting the entire code, it's a bit tricky to choose the right section, as I'm not sure which part of the code I should be looking at.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height"),
innerRadius = 180,
outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
.range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
.align(0);

var y = d3.scaleRadial()
.range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.range(<?php echo json_encode($plotColors);?>);
```

I expect the rings to be equal distance from each other, however, they get closer as they move out from the center.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

var y = d3.scaleLinear() does the trick